# Chat Invitation using XMPPHP

Tags: php, xmpp, google-talk

Is it possible to send chat invitations using XMPPHP?

I have successfully setup the messaging system from a CMS, but I am looking for a way to send chat request before the first message is sent.

Is it possible to do that in XMPPHP? I am asking this because I could not find any proper documentation for the class. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in XMPP, we don't send a request first, we just send the first message.  If you MUST have this feature, you'll want the protocol from [XEP-155](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0155.html) (Stanza Session Negotiation).  You'll likely need to implement this protocol yourself, and also deal with the case where the client on the other side doesn't implement the protocol... mostly because NOBODY has implemented this. :)

Comment: @Joe: Met with a road accident and sorry for the delayed response. I didn't mention in the question that I am looking to send requests to Google Apps accounts. Any idea whether Google has implemented this protocol? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody has implemented this protocol to my knowledge, including Google.  I'd just send the message first, without negotiating.  If you feel like you need to negotiate, it's likely because you haven't fully internalized XEP-115 (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) yet, which *is* widely implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I shall read through those protocols and decide on how to move about.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below for send chat invitation.

```
$conn->subscribe('$jid');
```

by

```
$conn->unsubscribe('$jid');
```

you can remove jid from your contact list